# Can I use Wiha "Micro Bit" bits with regular 1/8'' hex screwdriver?

Tags: hand-tools, screwdriver, bits

Wiha says their micro bits are 4mm in diameter, and suggests to use special adapter for 1/4 screwdriver. Obviously these 4mm micro bits are smaller than 1/4 inch, but are they compatible with 1/8 hex driver?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how they would be compatible.

¼" = 6.35mm
⅛" = 3.175mm

Answer (score 1):

A 4mm to 1/4" adapter would work, but the effort to make one would be about the same as the effort to make a 4mm driver and handle.

That said, wiha make one already, and its under $5 US.   Wiha's SKU is 75802

https://www.wihatools.com/micro-bit-to-1-4-drive-insert-bit-adapter